# Creating Decorators in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn decorator concept

I am doing this

```js
function calculateArea(length, width){
  return length * width;
}

function checkData(fn){
  return function(...args){
    if(args.length != 2){
      return false;
    }
    return fn(...args)
  }
}

let checked = checkData(calculateArea(2,3));
```

I am getting this error
`Uncaught TypeError: fn is not a function`
Also what is the purpose of returning a function here?

Comment: Your code calls the function and assigns what it returns to checkData. For checkData to work, `let checked = checkData(calculateArea)(2,3);` is how you would have to call that

Comment: That's not decorating, that's just calling two functions. You probably want `const checkedCalculatedArea = checkData(calculateArea)`.

Comment: let checked = checkData( calculateArea ); -THEN-> checked( 2, 3 );

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind your code is to enhance/wrap any function that wants two parameters by making sure it returns  `false` if the number of parameters is not exactly 2.

To make your code example work, you need to pass a **reference** to the `calculateArea` function to `checkdata`, which will return an "enriched" function that does the aforementioned, and only **then** call it:

```js
function calculateArea(length, width){
  return length * width;
}

function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}

function checkData(fn){
  return function(...args){
    if(args.length != 2){
      return false;
    }
    return fn(...args)
  }
}

let checked = checkData(calculateArea)(2,3);
console.log(checked);

let myName = checkData(fullName)('John', 'Doe');
console.log(myName);
```

Using this concept allows to reduce redundancy in your code. As you can see, I don't do any checks inside `calculateArea` or `fullName` functions, and using `checkData` I still easily get functions that return `false` if the number of arguments is not exactly two.

Answer (score 0):

```
.....

let checked = checkData(calculateArea(2,3));
```

The argument "calculateArea(2,3)" is getting run first so it returns the result of (length*width)
and not a function.